# No space between components on smaller display

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I try to add styles to two components in order to achieve space between them (having the space on bigger display and on smaller), a source code look like:

```
<div>
  <CustomPageHeader
    pageTitle={t('offersPage.pageHeader')}
    buttonLabel={t('offersPage.newRequestButton')}
    buttonHandler={handleRequest}
  />
  <Grid classes={{ root: classes.container }} container spacing={4}>
    <Filter
      onFilter={(payload) => {
        // setSelectedFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...payload }));
        if (payload === null) {
          setData(sourceData);
          return null;
        }
        // filltering by offerId
        if (payload.offerId !== undefined) {
          const filteredData = sourceData.filter(
            (item) => payload.offerId === item.offerId.toString(),
          );
          setData(filteredData);
          return null;
        }
        // filtering by timestamp
        if (payload.time !== undefined) {
          const filteredData = sourceData.filter((item) => payload.time < item.timestamp);
          setData(filteredData);
          payload.time = null;
          return null;
        }
      }}
    >
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <SingleSelection
          fullWidth={false}
          parameter={'time'}
          className={classes.select}
          defaultValue="1608969777"
          items={[
            ['Last 30 days', 1608969777],
            ['Last 10 days', 1613548977],
            ['Last day', 1613462577],
          ]}
          required
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <Autosuggestion
          className={classes.autosuggestion}
          parameter={'offerId'}
          valueAsParameter={true}
          options={sourceData.map((option) => option.offerId.toString())}
          freeSolo
          searchIcon
          hintInDropdown
          fullWidth={true}
          placeholder={t('offersPage.searchForButton')}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Filter>
    {data.map((offer, index) => (
      <Grid item container xs={12} spacing={0} key={index}>
        <Card xs={12} lg={12}>
          <Grid item container style={{ flexWrap: 'nowrap' }} xs={11}>
            <Chip className={classes.chip} color="success" label="Open"></Chip>
            <Grid xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
              <CardHeader
                className={classes.cardheader}
                actions={
                  <Button
                    className={classes.buttonDetails}
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={function noRefCheck() {}}
                  >
                    {t('offersPage.detailsButton')}
                  </Button>
                }
                subtitle="Customer reference: 43232 / 2342342"
                title="Trumpf Maschinen Austria GmbH and Co.KG"
              ></CardHeader>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <CardDivider classes={{ horizontal: classes.divider }} />
          <CardContent container>
            <Grid xs={2} item>
              <Typography variant="overline">{t('offersPage.validUntil')}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{offer.validUntil}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={2} item>
              <Typography variant="overline">{t('offersPage.offerId')}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{offer.offerId}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={2} item>
              <Typography variant="overline">{t('offersPage.total')}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{offer.total}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={2} item>
              <Typography variant="overline">{t('offersPage.parts')}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{offer.parts}</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
</div>
```

and it is what I got:

[image]

On bigger display works margin works but on smaller does not, any idea how to solve it? Grid is taken from `ui-material` library.

Comment: Hard to say without css. Is the `Grid` component created by you or are you using external library?

Comment: It is ui-material

Comment: I dont how material ui grid works but you should  take a look at default css - grids. Margins in a grid are given by grid-gap so check if the parent component has grid-gap or not.

Comment: Not sure if that is related, in the docs I can see `<Grid container spacing={3}>` for example. Do you have similar setup?

Comment: Yes, the whole comonent is in the Grid container.

Comment: In that case I suggest you to post a complete example, as the way your question stands at the moment has not got enough details to understand the problem.

Comment: Posted the whole div

Comment: You have `spacing={4}` on your grid container, so that should be consistent across devices. Do you have any custom css which overrides padding on smaller devices? Specifically for `.MuiGrid-item`

Comment: None, I do not have overriding at all.

Comment: Works fine in this example -> https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ddwyf?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a margin, try adding spacing to a new parent element:

```
<Grid container spacing={16}>    
  <Grid item xs={2}></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2}></Grid>
</Grid>
```